# Show jQmodal window for the first time only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqmodal

I am using jQmodal plugin , to show pop up window, welcome to site.

But the issue is every time page refresh window pop-up.

Here is my code http://jsbin.com/atoqe5/3/edit

I think it can be done using Cookies, but not much Idea how to use that. :(

Thanks!

Comment: Wich server side language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a cookie with JavaScript and set it to true when it's opened for the first time.

These are just helper functions for setting and getting cookie values, [more info about setting and getting cookie values](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp).

```
function setCookie(name, value, daysToLive) {
    var expirationDate = new Date();
    expirationDate.setDate(expirationDate.getDate() + daysToLive);
    document.cookie = name + '=' + escape(value) + ((daysToLive == null) ? '' : '; expires=' + expirationDate.toUTCString());
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookies=document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        if (cookies[i].substr(0, cookies[i].indexOf('=')).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') == name) {
            return unescape(cookies[i].substr(cookies[i].indexOf('=') + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Prevent the modal from opening if the value is set:

```
$(function() {
    if (!getCookie('modalOpened')) {
        // Put your code to open the model here...

        // Set value to true to prevent the modal from opening again 
        setCookie('modalOpened', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php you can do something like this: put in each page as first line

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

and in you homepage

```
<?php session_start();
  if( $_SESSION['visited'] ){
      //don't show the modal box
  } else {
      $_SESSION['visited'] = true;
     //show modal box;
  }
?>
```

This code check if you already visited the page in this session, if you don't shows the modal box, then set the global session variable `$_SESSION['visited']` to `true`, so you can be sure the user have already visited the page :)
hope this helped